# Testing JavaScript functions inside anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, testing

Is it possible to test `myInnerFunction` below?

```
var val = function() {
    var myInnerfunction = function(input) {
        return input + ' I ADDED THIS';
    };
    return myInnerfunction('test value');
}();
```

Because `myInnerFunction` is essentially a private member of the anonymously executed outer function, it doesn't seem like it is testable from the outside.

Comment: The answers are bringing up a broader question now. This was a trivial example. 

I have JS functions that are tied closely enough to an expected DOM structure that they are coupled to it, and cannot be pulled into a generic public utilities API. I need to test these functions; their logic is significant, but they are all declared on-DOM-ready within a function literal, and attached as event handlers to DOM elements. They are essentially private, and closely coupled to DOM structure, but I still need to test them.

Where should they reside in order for me to have access to them from my tests?

Comment: In order to take the methods I want to test out of the anonymous function that is executed on-dom-ready by the library, I namespaced them within a "package" that corresponds to the functionality going on in my page. Although this code will really only be used on this particular page, and only through the event handlers I've added to this specific DOM, at least I can test this logic now.  Thanks all of your for directing me. Any further thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my answer for this is (like so many things) that I'm doing it wrong.  What I've defined as a 'private' function is really something that needs to be tested.  It was only private because I didn't want to expose it within a utilities api or something like that. But it could still be exposed through my application namespace.

So within the anonymous function that is executed on-dom-ready, I just attach my pre-defined functions as event handlers to the proper DOM hooks.  The functions themselves, while not stored with my more open utilities functions, are still stored publicly within a package in my namespace associated with the DOM structure they are dealing with.  This way I can get at them and test them appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

You could intentionally expose a testing hook to the outside world, like possibly this:

```
var val = function() {
   var myInnerfunction = function(input) {
      return input + ' I ADDED THIS';
   };
   /* START test hook */
   arguments.callee.__test_inner = myInnerFunction;
   /* END test hook */
   return myInnerfunction('test value');
}();
```

now, once val has been run at least once, you can reference `val.__test_inner` and call it with testable inputs.

The benefits to this approach:
1. you choose what is exposed and not (also a negative 'cause you have to REMEMBER to do so)
2. all you get is a copy-reference to the private method, so you can't accidentally change it, only use it and see what it produces

The drawbacks:
1. if the private member changes (or relies on) state of its host/parent function, it's harder for you to unit test around that, since you have to recreate or artificially control the host/parent state at the same time
2. As mentioned, these hooks have to be manually added

If you got really clever, you could have your build process look for blocks of comments like the above and remove the test hooks when creating your production build.

Comment: I like your approach, although I do want to try to keep the production code as clean as possible. What I'm really doing is providing a function to a library's Dom-ready event handler, so I don't know if I could do this and still get access to it from the library.

Comment: that's exactly why i suggested the build-process strip out blocks of formatted comments like the above.

Answer (score 1):

afaik unit testing does not concern about internal workings of things you test. The point is that you test the functionality ie: it does **what** it's supposed to do, **not how** it does it.
So if it uses an internal private member, it *should* not be testable...

Answer (score 1):

You can test the external behavior that is observable. In this simple case you returned just the value of the inner function, but in a real world example you might combine the result of that inner function with something else. That combination is what you would test, not the direct outputs of the private method.

Trying to test the private method will make your code difficult to change and refactor, even when the external behavior is preserved. That said, I like to view unit tests not as extensive tests of your code, but simply providing an example of the API and how it behaves to different conditions. ;)